# Columns which are duplicate and not part of join condition of dataframes - How to remove in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two dataframes which have common column names.

df1 -> ID, Name, Address, Dept

df2 -> ID, Name, Address, Core

After I join them I get duplicate columns.

```
joinedDF = df1.join(df2,['ID'],"inner")
joinedDF.dtypes -> ID, Name, Address, Dept, Name, Address, Core
```

How do I remove duplicate columns which are not part of join? I want to take just one of the two duplicate columns. So the desired output would be -

```
joinedDF.dtypes -> ID, df1.Name, df2. Address, Dept, Core
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify join condition using column name as String or Array, then it will not result duplicate cols which are part of join cols(in your case it is one col "ID"), 
but other non joined columns can result duplicates.

As you have duplicates cols, which are not part of joining cols, Just select the required columns

```
joinedDF = df1.join(df2,['ID'],"inner").select(df1["ID"], df1["Name"], df2["Address"], df1["Dept"],df2["Core"])
```